# Dynamic Ribbon Button Size With XML Ribbon

Tags: outlook-addin, ribbonx

I have group of buttons I have added to the mail main group. Is there a setting in the XML to allow these buttons to re-size themselves based on the size of Outlook like the built in Outlook buttons? I only see the option of large and normal button sizes, and if I remove the size tag it will show up as normal. Is there an option for this? Couldn't find the tag reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto-scaling enables ribbon groups to adapt their layout to best match the horizontal window size. The auto-scaling feature was added to Office 2010 and onwards. You can enable auto-scaling by setting the autoScale attribute of the `<group>` tag to True as follows:

```
autoScale="true"
```

Note, auto-scaling is set on a per-group basis. See [Ribbon Extensibility in Office 2010: Tab Activation and Auto-Scaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691834(v=office.14).aspx) for more information.

Read more about the Fluent UI in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Sorry about accepting so late, was away for a while. This was perfect, thanks!